# Cannot read property 'create' of undefined in AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I got a console error in the amp page which is mentioned below,

`Cannot read property 'create' of undefined  in AMP pages`

[image]

I searched in GitHub and they mentioned to ignore the console error, but it is an old post.
Is there any way to remove the console error?

Answer (score 0):

Is your AMP page valid otherwise, can you provide us a link to your page. Also is this error in the console somehow preventing you from serving your page properly? Also provide a link to the GitHub post. Thanks